# Is there a way to make the MemberQ function apply to a list?

Tags: functions

Is there any way to ask a boolean question if the elements of the list {2,5} are in the list {1,2,3,4,5}?

Comment: `MemberQ[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, #] & /@ {2, 5}`?

Comment: Is there a way to code that without using shorthand notation.  I've had some problems using shorthand notation when writing longer pieces of code; I'm not very experienced yet.

Comment: You can still use `Table`: `Table[MemberQ[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, i], {i, {2, 5}}]`.

Comment: Do you need to test whether all elements of {2,5} are in the list or whether any one is present in the list?

Comment: I need if all of the elements of {2,5} are in the list.

Comment: @Kaisey When you reply to someone in a comment, you need to use the person's name, preceded by a @ character.  Otherwise they won't be notified.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Intersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Intersection.html) for good performance.

```
Union[{2,5}] === Intersection[{2,5},{1,2,3,4,5}]
```